# Solr 5.2 How does core auto-discovery work?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I am new to Solr world. I got a core indexed by Solr 4.6 and I want Solr 5.2 to take the existing core for searching. I have spent hours to figure out auto-discovery feature but no documentation exists.

My effort has been done here:

1) [Quick start](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html) guide only tells you how to create one in 5.2

2) **Upgrading a Solr 4.x Cluster to Solr 5.0** in [Official 5.2 documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/rsync.apache.org/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.2.pdf) touches the topic but does not provide useful hints (what is ZK_HOST? Why do I need it by the way?) . Plus, I don't want to make it a service without knowing it will work via command line.

I believe there must be a command option to set the core location and let Solr finds it. Could you share some useful hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way that you manage your Solr service changed quite a bit between 4.6 and 5.2.

First off, you now have a solr script in bin directory to manage the instance. You also have a solr.in.sh file for configuring your solr instance and you now stick all the solr configs in there, things like port, jvm parameters, etc...

Anyway, down to your question. Core Auto discovery scans your SOLR_HOME directory (specified in solr.in.sh) In that directory it expects to find directories that have core.properties files in them. Solr will try to attach any core it finds in there.

Other parameters like ZK_HOST are related to zookeeper. If you are running Solr Classic (with basic replication), you don't need to worry about that. However, if you are moving to SolrCloud, you will need to learn a bit about zookeeper.